# Surface Pro 3 won't connect to specific wi-fi network

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Work blocks access to a lot of sites, but there's an independent cafeteria in the building with free wifi.

For a few months my Surface would connect just fine. Sometimes though I would get a "limited" connection, and rebooting or restarting wi-fi on the Surface would work to get me the full connection. Unfortunately now I can only get the limited connection, and it's been like that for at least a couple weeks.

I've tried running the diagnostic, which just identifies this problem:

"vEthernet (Marvell AVASTAR Wireless-AC Network Controller Virtual Switch)" doesn't have a valid IP configuration  (not fixed)

I've tried turning off IPv6 on the adapter (no real reason, just guessing on that one) and also running ipconfig /renew which says it's unable to contact DHCP server.

Now, I might say it was a problem with the network except for one thing: *My phone connects just fine.*

So what else can I try to fix this on my Surface?

EDIT: There is no pin or password. It doesn't take you to a sign in page or anything, and I never had to use one for my phone.

Comment: Do you connect through a pin or a password? Is it free wifi as in they give you the password or anyone can connect to it.

Comment: There is no pin or password. It doesn't take you to a sign in page or anything, and I never had to use one for my phone. Forgot to put that in question... oops.

Comment: Have you tried removing the existing WiFi profile for that network and recreating it from scratch?

Comment: I had your problem in windows 8.1. After I upgrade the surface pro 3 to windows 10 my problem has been resolved. However, your OS is windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring a static IP adress, mask and default gateway for the Surface. But first run an IP scanner to see what IP adresses are already in use for that network to avoid IP conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Go to network settings click on wifi. Click on  "manage known networks" and delete all old versions of the connection (I found three the same). Restart the process as normal to sign up for a new connection put in the password.